# how can i force URLs to be case sensitive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

Say I have the domain mydomain.com, and what I want to do is force the browser to show MyDomain.com in the URL bar.  I have the following htaccess:

```
# force all to MyDomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.MyDomain
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.MyDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work.  Are there any tricks/hacks that can be done to make the browser show a URL that isn't all lowercase?  Or is this just not possible to do?

Comment: You would need to draft a new specification for URIs and have it accepted. Because in the [current URI specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), it says that the [host](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) is case-insensitive: “Although host
   is case-insensitive, producers and normalizers should use lowercase
   for registered names and hexadecimal addresses for the sake of
   uniformity, while only using uppercase letters for percent-encodings.”

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking for how to do it purely with htaccess.  That was just one technique that I thought could be used to achieve what I want.  All I'm really looking for is a way to make the user see the case-sensitive domain in his/her URL bar in the browser.

Answer (score 8):

Nope, domains and subdomains are always lowercase. The DNS system is always case insensitive.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4343

Comment: Okay, so basically achieving this via htaccess is not possible.  What about with javascript? Are there any known techniques that accomplish what I'm looking for? Essentially I just care about the user seeing it, not necessarily what goes on behind the scenes with DNS.

Comment: There is not. The browser will always show the domain as lowercase.